# get_delete_post_link redirect

Tags: front-end, customization

I am using this to allow users to delete their own posts on the front end of my site:

```
<a onclick="return confirm('Move this post to the trash? You can restore it later.');" href="<?php echo get_delete_post_link($postid); ?>">Trash Post</a>
```

The problem is, this refreshed the current page and adds some query args to the URL (trashed=1 and ids=123). What I want to happen is that the user is redirected to a certain page with specific query args, like so:

```
mysite.com/yourarticles/?user=123&post=321&action=trash
```

How can I change where the get_delete_post_link function redirects to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To redirect after the use of [`get_delete_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_delete_post_link) it's probably easiest to hook into the `trashed_post` action:

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing', 10 );
function wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing() {
    wp_redirect( home_url('/your-custom-slug') );
    exit;
}
```

Or you could make it dependent on the according `$_GET` variable by hooking into the the action `parse_request`:

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get' );
function wpse132196_redirect_after_trashing_get() {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'trashed', $_GET ) && $_GET['trashed'] == '1' ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/your-custom-slug') );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Note that both solution will intercept on the admin side too, so you might want to add a check to prevent that.

To change the link returned by [`get_delete_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_delete_post_link) take a look at the source, in [`link-template.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L957). There you'll see how the `$delete_link` is constructed. You can alter the return of the function via the correspondent filter [`get_delete_post_link`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L975). This way you can make the link point to your custom page or endpoint for frontend post deletion.

**Code:**

```
add_filter( 'get_delete_post_link', 'wpse132196_change_delete_post_link', 10, 3 );
function wpse132196_change_delete_post_link(  $id = 0, $deprecated = '', $force_delete = false ) {
    global $post;
    $action = ( $force_delete || !EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS ) ? 'delete' : 'trash';
    $qargs = array(
        'action' => $action,
        'post' => $post->ID,
        'user' => get_current_user_id()
    );
    $delete_link = add_query_arg( $qargs, home_url( sprintf( '/yourarcticles/' ) ) );
    return  wp_nonce_url( $delete_link, "$action-post_{$post->ID}" );
}
```

From where you can take care of handling your custom post deletion request. Note that above exemplary code won't delete anything, if I'm not mistaken, I haven't actually tested it, it's only proof of concept code, so you have to adapt to your needs yourself.

Comment: My pleasure, I hope you get it going with this. @Eckstein

Comment: Strangely the first example doesn't work with the check for `if (!is_admin())`.

Comment: @certainlyakey You are aware that [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) pretty much checks for being at the backend, administrative interface? So `! is_admin()` means we are viewing the theme. If you want to distinguish users, like administrators, use [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/).

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I meant exactly that — if you want to "allow users to delete their own posts on the front end" you don't want the redirect to happen in the admin. But with that check in place redirect doesn't work. The second example works nicely though (with few corrections of purely spelling nature).

Comment: @certainlyakey I see, I'm not 100% sure at the moment what the reason would be. Next time edit the answer to fix errors, it is allowed, I would even say encouraged, personally I appreciate it.

Comment: Funnily, I'm not allowed to save those edits — they're too short! It's just `=` -> `==` in the 2nd example.

Comment: @certainlyakey True, there is the six character limit. And there was a s in trashed missing. Anyhow I fixed it.

Comment: yes, those two problems. apart from that, thanks for the really useful answer with a lot of options to go.

Comment: @NicolaiGrossherr thank you for the excellent response. Is there a way you suggest we create a conditional that redirects depending on the deleted post type?